# variable assignment with switch in coffescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, switch-statement

How to use switch for assignment in coffescript?
Tried many ways but couldn't make it work.

```
item = { name: "ahola" }
arr = "coffee_script"

switch arr
 when arr.match /script/
   item.type = arr

 alert item.name + " : " + item.type
 # alerts  "ahola : undefined"
```

even this doesn't work

```
item = { name: "ahola" }
arr = "coffee_script"

switch arr
 when arr == "coffee_script"
   item.type = arr

alert item.name + " : " + item.type
# alerts  "ahola : undefined"
```

tried this way also

```
item = { name: "ahola" }
arr = "coffee_script"

item.type = switch arr
 when arr.match /script/
   arr

alert item.name + " : " + item.type
# alerts  "ahola : undefined"
```

At last found this also doesn't work

```
item = { name: "ahola" }
arr = "coffee_script"

item.type = switch arr
 when true
   arr

alert item.name + " : " + item.type
# alerts  "ahola : undefined"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two forms of [`switch` in CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#switch):

```
switch expr
  when expr1
    result1
  ...
  else
    default_result
```

and

```
switch
  when expr1
    result1
  ...
  else
    default_result
```

Both forms are, of course, expressions so you can say:

```
x = switch expr
  when val then result
  ...
```

and

```
x = switch
  when expr then result
  ...
```

The `switch expr` is like a JavaScript `switch`: you compare the result of `expr` with each `when` expression and execute the `when` that is `==` to `expr`. This form of `switch` is the same as:

```
if(expr == expr1)
  result1
else if(expr == expr2)
  result2
...
else
  default_result
```

The `switch ... when` form executes the first `when expr` where `expr` is true so it is a fancy way of saying:

```
if(expr1)
  result1
else if(expr2)
  result2
...
else
  default_result
```

All of your attempts appear to be trying to mix the two forms of `switch` and confusion ensues.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
arr = "coffee_script"
switch arr
  when 'coffee_script'
    item.type = arr
  ...
```

Comment: Well, this is a great explanation. Thank You.